# Can't figure out what a loop with a binning lambda function does

Tags: python, pandas, loops, lambda

This structure is part of a vastly larger project, but I can't seem to figure out how the lambda portion of this works:

```
for num in range(1,100):
    dataframe[f'n{num}_bins'] = dataframe[f'n{num}'].apply(
        lambda x: 0 if x < 1
        else 1 if x < 2
        else 2 if x < 3
        else 3 if x < 4
        else 4 if x < 5
        else 5 if x < 6
        else 6
```

What does lambda check for, exactly?

Comment: It is used to create in line function. example: ```func = lambda x: print(x)``` is the same as ```def func(x): print(x)```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each row (this is what `apply` does) in the `f'n{num}'` column (and for each such column, as per the outer loop):

if the value `x` at that location is smaller than:

- `1` -> return `0`
- `2` -> return `1`

...

- `6` -> return `5`
- otherwise (values `>=6`) -> return `6`

Look into [Does Python have a ternary conditional operator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator)

Answer (score 0):

Convert the `lambda` function to normal function, you will know what's going on:

```py
def func(x):
    if x < 1:
        return 0
    elif x < 2:
        return 1
    elif x < 3:
        return 2
    elif x < 4:
        return 3
    elif x < 5:
        return 4
    elif x < 6:
        return 5
    else:
        return 6
```

Generally, when you have so many conditions, using `lambda` is very unpythonic and is not recommended either.

You are confused with above `lambda` because it appears to be very ambiguous and unreadable.